# Unidirectional One-To-One relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

Below example of one-to-one relationship throws an exception

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Exception says:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'ConsoleApplication1.Address' and 'ConsoleApplication1.User'.
>   The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured
>   using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

it works if i remove User property from Address but i don't want.

How can i have such a relationship without an exception ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the answer provided by Eranga is correct and creates a [shared primary key association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) between User and Address, you might not want to use it due to the limitations this mapping type has.

Here is another way of creating a 1:1 association which is called [one-to-one foreign key association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.User)
                .WithOptional(u => u.Address)
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"));
}
```

EF Code First recognizes this as a 1:1 association hence allowing you to have a bidirectional association between User and Address.

Now all you need to do is to define a Unique Key constraint on the UserId column to make your relationship a true one to one on your database side. One way for doing so is using a Seed method that has been overridden in a custom initializer class:

```
class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Addresses ADD CONSTRAINT uc_User UNIQUE(UserId)");
    }
}
```

The above code will result in the following schema:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to use fluent API to map the relationship as shared primary key.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
             .HasRequired(a => a.User)
             .WithOptional(u => u.Address);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have exactly did what you have said and dbcontext created database without any problem. But when i check tables i see that there is no any relation between user and address tables. huhhh

Comment: @Freshblood The PK of `Address` should also be an FK to `User` table PK.

Comment: I couldn't understand what i have to do

Comment: @Freshblood If you allow EF to create the database(eg: using an `IDatabaseInitializer`) it will create the FK mentioned above.

Comment: @Erange Have you tried it ? I have tried in simple app and it did not created really.