# Unidirectional One to One relationship entity framework, cascade delete doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to implement a unidirectional one to one relationship; however on cascade delete doesn't work.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    //I don't want the StudentId foreign key or the property of Student class here 
}
```

In my Context class, I'm mapping the relationship like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Address)
        .WithOptional()
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("Address_Id"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

For some reason, it's not deleting the `address` when, `student` object is deleted.

Moreover, I also want to add the foreign key property (i.e. `AddressId`) in the `Student` class like this:

```
[ForeignKey("Address")]
[Column("Address_Id")]
public string AddressId { get; set; }
```

However, I get this error when I try to add a new migration:

> Address_Id: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'Address_Id' is already defined.

I do believe I'm mixing things up (with `MapKey` and the attributes of `AddressId`). However, I don't know how to fix this.

---

*I went through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466660/unidirectional-one-to-one-relationship-in-entity-framework) and [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations); however, no luck so far.*

***Link to [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eS4h1M). It won't work cause there is no database.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For some reason, it's not deleting the `address` when, `student` object is deleted.

That's the normal behavior for the relationship you have defined. It's not a matter of data annotations or fluent configuration. If you have different expectations, you'd better revisit your model.

Every relationship has a one side called **principal** and another side called *dependent*. The **principal** side (a.k.a. master, primary) is the one being referenced. The *dependent* side (a.k.a. detail, secondary) is the one that is referencing the **principal**. The foreign key is put on the *dependent* side and must always point to an existing **principal** or `null` when the relationship is `optional`. The `cascade delete` works by deleing all the *dependent* records when the **principal** record is deleted.

As explained in the *How Code First Determines the Principal and Dependent Ends in an Association?* section of the [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) mentioned by you, EF always uses the `required` side as **principal** and allows you to chose the one only when both are `required`.

With all that being said, let see what you have.

`Address` is `required`, `Student` is `optional`. Also you want to put FK in `Student`, i.e. `Student` references `Address`.

All that means that in your relationship, `Address` is the **principal** and `Student` is the *dependent*. Which means the `Address` may exists w/o `Student` referencing it. If `cascade delete` is turned on (as you did), deleting the `Address` will delete the `Student`, not the opposite.

I think all that should explain why it's is working the way it is now, and that no attributes or configuration can help to achieve what are you asking for. If you want it differently, the same article (and related from the same series) explains how to configure the relationship to either use *Shared Primary Key Association* or *Foreign Key Association* at the **Address** side. Whether it is unidirectional or bidirectional absolutely has nothing in common with the problem - see `Should We Make the Associations Bidirectional?` section in the article.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You foreign key should be like this :

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }        
    [Column("Address_Id")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

In your fluent mapping you just need:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Address)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Or you can force cascade delete with an annotation:

```
[Required]
[ForeignKey("AddressId")]
public Address Address { get; set; }
```

Now update your database and your mapping should be correct and the delete should cascade.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry; however, the fluent mapping doesn't seem to work. `Required` annotation does work. However, EF doesn't load the `Address` object unless the `virtual` keyword is added to the property. Is it supposed to behave like that? Does the `virtual` keyword helps in lazy loading only when an `ICollection` is supposed to be retrieved?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just looked into my database. Cascade delete doesn't work either.

Comment: Virtual keyword lazy loads the related entity so the entity gets loaded when the parent object is loaded. Eager loading is when you add Include() onto the linq to entity query so there are 2 choices.

Comment: Thanks James. Hopefully, I'm going to use the `Required` annotation. Currently, I can see `cascadeDelete` is set to `true` for the students table (in the migration file); however, `localdb` is acting funny for some reason. I have another question though. `Required` annotation would also make the foreign key non-nullable. Is there any way I can make foreign key `nullable`?

Comment: You can make the foreign key nullable by making the property a nullable int? but that would not make the entity [Required] as this means the relationship is always required on the entity. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well, now I'm using `[Required]` just cause I want to do cascade delete (fluent mapping doesn't work for some reason). So, my scenario here is "nullable foreign key with cascade delete".